# Accessing arrays in another instance of a class objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have a `@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *transfer_array;` in .h file and in my .m I have

```
@synthesize transfer_array = _transfer_array;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.transfer_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and I add objects to the array in this function

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
- (id)display:(double)imageXX andY:(double)imageYY withName:(NSString *)namee{

    //if((self == [super init])){
    NSLog(@"````````````````````````````````````````````````````````");

    NSLog(@"imageX: %f",imageXX);
    NSLog(@"imageY: %f", imageYY);
    NSLog(@"name: %@", namee);

    labelPoi = [[Poi alloc] init];
    labelPoi.imageLocationX = imageXX;
    labelPoi.imageLocationY = imageYY;
    labelPoi.name = namee;
    [self.transfer_array addObject:labelPoi];
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

The objects add successfully bu whenever I try to access the array elements in another instance such as:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"transfer_array count: %lu",(unsigned long)self.transfer_array.count);
```

Then the array is empty.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You mean another instance of that class? The array is only usable in an instance. If you have two instances of that class you have two separate instances of that array.

Comment: Don't your viewDidLoad gets called first, and afterwards the `- (id)display:(double)imageXX andY:(double)imageYY withName:(NSString *)namee{` function?

Could you insert `NSLog(@"transfer_array count: %lu",(unsigned long)self.transfer_array.count);` in your display function, after you added the object to the array and show us the output?

Comment: I call display in another view controller before this view loads. Maybe I dont have my terminology correct, essentially when I attempt to use the array in another function, the array is empty

Comment: Also, I do have a  `NSLog(@"transfer_array count: %lu",(unsigned long)self.transfer_array.count);` in the display function and the result is `2013-07-30 12:44:57.002 App[24164:11303] transfer_array count: 2`

Answer (score 3):

Instances are independent objects.  Changing the internal state of one doesn't affect the internal state of others.